# Kibana/Logstash Time Issue

Tags: time, logstash, kibana, elk

Task: Send CSV formatted records to logstash for parsing.

The Good: All parsing works. All CSV pieces are split into individual fields that can be seen in kibana.

The Bad: All fields that carry a date are inaccurate. The date is a day behind and it includes a time that is always 18:00:00. There was never a time provided in the CSV before parsing. No time was ever added in the logstash configuration. But for some reason there's a time there when seen in kibana.

The Details:
The format of the dates from the CSV is: YYYY-MM-DD.

The logstash config ONLY parses the fields. It does no conversion and no other modification. It's a very simple config.

The problem must lie somewhere in kibana or elasticsearch.

Any thoughts on how to fix that?
*Note: same issue occurs in a docker container.

Here's screen shot:
[image]

Time: Accurate.

SMF30DTE field: A day behind and includes a time that should not be there.

SMF30TME: Accurate.

Here's my logstash filter:

```
filter {
    split {
    }
    mutate { 
        add_field => {"[@metadata][indexname]" => "%{[sourceType]}-%{[sysplexName]}"}
    }
    mutate { 
        lowercase => [ "[@metadata][indexname]" ]
    }
    if [source] =~ "table" {
        csv{ columns => [  "Correlator", "SMF30LEN", "SMF30SEG", "SMF30FLG", "SMF30RTY","<shortened for ease of reading>" ]
        separator => "," }
    }
}
```

Comment: Somewhere your date is being treated as if it were a timestamp at midnight UTC, and then getting converted to local time using a UTC-6 time zone offset (such as US Central Standard Time).  Since you didn't show us any of your code, config, schema, etc. it's difficult to tell you more than that.  Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help center.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I added my code from my Logstash filter. There isn't really much else I can add. I guess I'm hoping for someone who knows how elastic search indexing works, because that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All dates stored in Elasticseach are in UTC, when you use Kibana to visualize elasticsearch data it will, per default, convert the time in UTC to the correspondent browser timezone.

Since your field `SMF30DTE` only has the date in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, it will be indexed as being at midnight of the date in UTC time, so `2019-11-15` will be indexed as `2019-11-15 00:00:00.000` and will be show in Kibana according to your browser timezone, which seems to be `UTC -0600` because you are seeing the date as `2019-11-14 18:00:00.000`

I don't think Kibana supports showing date fields without time at the moment, so to solve your problem you can use a `mutate` filter to add time to your field and after that a `date` filter to convert it to your timezone, something like this:

```
mutate {
    add_field => { "SMF30DTE" => "%{SMF30DTE} 00:00:00.000" }
}
date {
    match => [ "SMF30DTE", "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"]
    target => "SMF30DTE"
    timezone => "-0600"
}
```

This should at least make your dates appear in kibana with the correct day.

Another option is to create a mapping for your index and map the field `SMF30DTE` as being a string instead of letting elasticsearch do the dynamic mappings, but this way you will see the value `2019-11-15`, unless you use a combination of [`mutate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-add_field) and [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) filters to change the string to `November 15th, 2019`

Comment: I'm going to modify my code then, this seems like it should answer my question. I think you might be exactly right because that all makes perfect sense to me! I'll let you know if it works. Thank you!

Comment: So this did work except that I was not able to overwrite the SMF30DTE field. Instead I create a new field called SMF30DATE which was the combination of SMF30DTE and SMF30TME (the time) and that was accurate! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with these technologies, but it seems perhaps the issue is that Logstash doesn't have date-only parsing.  Instead, it assumes midnight UTC during the parsing, and then Kibana displays it based on your local time zone.  There's [an open GitHub issue on this](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/10575), where others have mentioned the problem you are describing.

I also found some information [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-timezone/29270) about how to adjust Kibana's time zone.  You could try setting Kibana's time zone to align to your source input.  Of course, then all of your other timestamps would also be in terms of UTC.

Alternatively, you could try setting `timezone => "America/Chicago"` in the Logstash date filter.  Though that would only help with viewing from US Central Time.